# Eating between Mincha and Maariv on Friday night

Tags: shabbat, eating

Can a person eat kiddush items on Friday night right after davening Mincha, and before praying Maariv?

Assume that person has someone to remind him to pray Maariv and has not made kiddush yet.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Shlomo and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: What are “kiddush items”?

Comment: Is it sunset yet?